Is there any way to import/export in/from DOORS automatically without DXL scripting
Is it possible to import or export automatically a file in DOORS(CSV, Excel, XML, etc.) with something like a command line?
Found a post from 2017 that stated the only way to do it was either manually or use some DXL scripting and parse trough the file/objects. Has anything changes since?
Took a peak inside some DXL helper manual but did not find anything related to import or export without any processing.
While we do have a team that could provide such DXL scripts, it will take a significant amount of time due to various reasons so I'm looking for a possible alternative that does not involve me learning how to create such DXL scripts.

There might be 3rd party tools (as in "dxl scripts created by other companies"). But generally, no, any way of doing things automatically uses DXL or other APIs, e.g. OSLC API or C API, ergo programming for import. For export, "IBM Lifecycle Optimization - Publishing (PUB)" might help you.

What is the underlying requirement? Are you trying to import as an unattended batch job, simplify the steps for a logged-in user to reduce either training needs or errors and inconsistencies, or something else?
